# UICollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind request order

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I was debugging my application and I perceived a very strange behavior in every single `UICollectionView` it has.

I have a `UICollectionView` with many sections, each one with its own header. As long as I have headers in it, I have to implement the following callback:

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
```

But the problem I am having is, when the `UICollectionView` is first loaded or the user scrolls it down/up, the order of header's position that pass through that callback is not ordered. Instead of calling in a sequence of header's position like {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...}, it scrambles it to something like {0, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7...}

Is there anything I can do to force the callback to be called "correctly" -> in an ordered way?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @Shruti, no code is needed. It seems to be the default behavior of a `UICollectionView`. It is more kinda of a theoretical question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure ,the relationship between them is hash, like Dictionary, not Array.
You can make them look like model.

```
 class DataSourceModel{
 var title  
}
```

that is better. 
I hope can help to you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @shaun. Do you mind explaining further, please? Cheers :)

Comment: Do you know MVC 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Make your data or JSON transform to be  a object, you can operate them more flexibly